# Составить программу вычисления числового ряда для известного числа членов ряда N [qBasic]

Tags: qbasic

Здравствуйте, Уважаемые кодеры.

Была поставлена задача:

```
Составить программу вычисления числового ряда для известного числа членов ряда N
Y=(3+1-1/81)(5-2+1/27)(7+3-1/9)(9-4+1/3)...
```

Вот написал решение на qBasic

```
CLS
10 INPUT "N"; N
IF N < 1 THEN
    PRINT "ERROR"
    GOTO 10
END IF
A = 3
B = 1
C = 81
Y = 1
FOR I = 1 TO N
    IF I / 2 = INT(I / 2) THEN
        Y = Y * ((A - B) + (1 / C))
    END IF
    IF I / 2 <> INT(I / 2) THEN
        Y = Y * ((A + B) - (1 / C))
    END IF
    A = A + 2
    B = B + 1
    C = C / 3
NEXT
PRINT Y
```

Всё ли верно? Так же, если ввести большое число N, то ответ будет #INF, что делать в таком случае?

Спасибо огромное.

Comment: А зачем что-то делать. Числа растут как o(3^n). Надеюсь, преподавателю не требуется ответ для n > log(max_int)/log(3). (Да я и не уверен, что там целые числа -- в basic'ах, где различия целые/действительные есть, целые переменные имели процент в конце имени).

Нет у меня квасика -- проверить не на чем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код вроде верный (я не уверен, целочисленное в бейсике деление, или с плавающей запятой).

По поводу огромных чисел -- целое число в бейсике (да и почти во всех других языках) ограничено, так что переполнение так просто не обойти. Решением было бы использование чисел произвольной точности. В некоторых языках они доступны (непосредственно или в виде библиотек), в некоторых приходится реализовывать самостоятельно. Не уверен насчёт вашего диалекта бейсика.